# Update record only if another column matches?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to develop a simple tracking system. What I'm trying to do is either insert the new record or update the record IF it matches the same campaign. I want to insert a new record if the user is triggered on a new campaign. Here is my current query that work fine.

```
INSERT INTO `tracking` (`email`,`ip`,`referrer`,`campaign`,`timestamp`) 
VALUES ('$campaign[0]','$ip','$referrer','$campaign[1]','$timestamp') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `last_timestamp` = '$timestamp'
```

My goal is if joe@bob.net triggers campaign1, then it will INSERT the record. If he tries campaign 1 again, it just updates the timestamp. Now when joe@bob.net triggers campaign2, it inserts an entirely new record.

So basically I'm trying to get it to INSERT only when the user triggers a new campaign. Otherwise, I want it to update the timestamp.

Any ideas or advice I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: `on duplicate key` only works on unique keys - you'd have add a unique key on the `campaign` field for this to work.

Comment: but does mysql check both keys or just the primary?

Comment: It checks all unique keys in the table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, all you need is a unique key put on the 'email' and 'campaign' columns on your table:

ALTER TABLE `tracking` ADD UNIQUE KEY `uk_email_campaign` (`email`, `campaign`);

Comment: I had no idea you could do that. I'm still learning so I really appreciate the help it worked perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a unique key on (email, campaign) -

```
ALTER TABLE `tracking`
    ADD UNIQUE INDEX `UQ_email_campaign` (`email`, `campaign`);
```